# how to add a interceptor on flask like in struts2

Tags: python, flask

I want to process some event befor every request. 
For example, to judge a user login befor he route to "/article/edit" or other routes.

like interceptor in struts2 , thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds to me like a classic case for [python function decorators](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/). Flask already has these defined as [View Decorators](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/) The login required decorator is one such decorator.